# Client of ActionCable on Heroku not receiving data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

My rails(5.0.0beta4) (and actioncable) works good locally.

But on heroku, the browser seems not to receive any data from the actioncable stream.

Here is my heroku setup:

I am using redis-to-go addon

```
production: &production
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://redistogo:[password]@hoki.redistogo.com:9079/
  host: hoki.redistogo.com
  port: 9079
  password: [password]
  inline: true
  timeout: 10
```

In `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_cable.url = "https://duewiz.herokuapp.com/cable"
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = ["https://duewiz.herokuapp.com",/http:\/\/duewiz.herokuapp.com.*/]
```

Here I tried wss and https protocol, but neither works.

In `routes.rb`

    `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`

And in `app/assets/javascripts/channels/cable.coffee.erb`

```
#= require action_cable
#= require_self
#= require_tree .
#
@App ||= {}
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer()
```

I have run `redis-cli monitor` on the redis-to-go server, it prints out the data from my `ActionCable.broadcast` calls

In heroku logs, I can see the `ActionCable` broadcasts

But I can't see any change in my browser, but things work just fine locally.

I have run `heroku restart` for each deployment

I also recall one thing that I use devise/warden for auth(also for actioncable)

```
module ApplicationCable
    class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
      identified_by :current_user

        def connect
          self.current_user = find_verified_user
          logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
        end

      protected
        def find_verified_user
          if verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
            verified_user
          else
            reject_unauthorized_connection
          end
        end
    end
end
```

So how should I configure actioncable for deployment on heroku?

Thanks for help.

---

Thanks pdoherty926. There is no javascript error in my browser console.

Comment: Are there any errors in your JavaScript console?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of that. But there is no javascript error in browser's dev tool console.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?